Infer the type to a class property based on another class method returning a conditional type
I'm trying to infer the type of a class property based on a method's conditional type returning from another class.
The Parent class property is assigned within the Builder class method, it has to be like that.
The code has to be like this.
The real scenario is much more complicated with decorators and more dependencies, but at the end it works like this:
class ClassA {
  propString: string
}

class ClassB {
  propNumber: number
}

type TypeAConstructor = new () => ClassA
type TypeBConstructor = new () => ClassB

class Builder {
  body: ClassA | ClassB

  build<T extends TypeAConstructor | TypeBConstructor>(Ctr: T, parent: Parent): T extends TypeAConstructor ? ClassA : ClassB {
    // I have to instantiate in this way, the real scenario is much more complex, but at the end it works like this
    if (new Ctr() instanceof ClassA) {
      this.body = new ClassA()
    } else {
      this.body = new ClassB()
    }
    // Parent obj will be assigned from this method
    parent.obj = this.body

    // Return type is correct
    return this.body as any // If I don't set as any, typescript throws an error
  }
}

class Parent {
  obj: ClassA | ClassB // ** Type should be inferred here. How to do it? **
  builder: Builder = new Builder()

  constructor() {
    const body = this.builder.build(ClassA, this)
    // body type is correct, it is ClassA
    // this.obj has no type, and it should be ClassA
  }
}


It's impossible. If build() mutates one of its arguments, then TS cannot reasonably modify the type of that argument. You could almost use assertion functions, but that won't allow the obj field type to be inferred. If you can change build() so it just returns the thing instead of mutating anything, as shown in this playground link then it will work. But since you've said multiple times "it has to be like that", then the answer is "then this is impossible". Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz the answer is correct. Go ahead and thanks.

As asked, this is impossible.
The only facility TypeScript has for inferring the type of a class field is if you explicitly initialize the field or explicitly assign it in the constructor. But inside the Parent constructor you are only implicitly assigning the obj property from by calling another method.  TypeScript does not track such things across function or method boundaries.
Well, you could make Builder's build() into an assertion function that narrows its second argument, but this doesn't interact with class field initialization at all. So that doesn't work.  If you are required to allow build() to mutate one of its arguments, then you'll have to just work around it by manually annotating and asserting types:
class Parent {
  obj!: ClassA; // can't infer
  builder: Builder = new Builder()

  constructor() {
    const body = this.builder.build(ClassA, this)
  }
}

But I'd strongly recommend not mutating things, and instead just do initialization the "normal" way:
class Builder {

    body?: ClassA | ClassB

    build<T extends TypeAConstructor | TypeBConstructor>(Ctr: T):
        T extends TypeAConstructor ? ClassA : ClassB {
            ⋯
    }
}

class Parent {
    obj; // now inferred as ClassA
    builder: Builder = new Builder()
    constructor() {
        this.obj = this.builder.build(ClassA) // assigned
    }
}

Such an approach does not fit the needs of the person asking this question, but future readers might benefit.
Playground link to code

Thanks jcalz for the detailed answer. The main problem is in the real code, Parent isn't executing anything, so it can't assign obj, build() is executed from a user's decorator class method opaque to Parent, that's why obj is aassigned within Builder. As you mention there's no way to infer that, since the user can execute build() at any point with any value. I will use generics in this case, so the user can explicity say which type will return build() on the decorator class implementation.
